# Passing Props in React Router

Tags: reactjs

I am having difficulty passing props via react router. Based on my understanding, there is a new way to pass props in React Router V6.

However, the props is still not showing up. Can some one take a look? thank you.

The props I am trying to pass is `<Route path="/products" element={< Products sortBy={'newest'} />} />`

Index.js

```html
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';
import {BrowserRouter} from 'react-router-dom'

ReactDOM.render(
<BrowserRouter>
       <App/>
</BrowserRouter>, document.getElementById('root'));
registerServiceWorker();
```

App.js

```
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import NavBar from "./components/navbar";
import Products from "./components/products";
import Posts from "./components/posts";
import Home from "./components/home";
import Dashboard from "./components/admin/dashboard";
import ProductDetails from "./components/productDetails";
import NotFound from "./components/notFound";
import {Routes, Route} from 'react-router-dom'
import "./App.css";

class App extends Component {

  
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <NavBar />
        <div className="content">
         <Routes>
            <Route path="/products" element={< Products sortBy={'newest'} />} />
            <Route path="/posts/2018/06" element={<Posts/>} />
            <Route path="/admin" element={<Dashboard/>} />
            <Route path="/" element={<Home/>} />
          </Routes>
     

        </div>
      


      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;


Product.js

    import React, { Component } from "react";

class Products extends Component {
  state = {
    products: [
      { id: 1, name: "Product 1" },
      { id: 2, name: "Product 2" },
      { id: 3, name: "Product 3" }
    ]
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Products</h1>
        <ul>
          {this.state.products.map(product => (
            <li key={product.id}>
              <a href={`/products/${product.id}`}>{product.name}</a>
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Products;
```

Comment: By `props` are you referring to the single prop being passed here `sortBy`? If so, no - there is no other way to pass props to components than the one here. If you are not seeing the prop, you'll need to provide more details.

Comment: Which component are you trying to pass the props to? Post that component's code as well

Answer (score 1):

You are passing the props correctly. Can you please attach the code inside your **`<Products/>`** component?
Also, to enable routing in your react project, you need the implementations **BrowserRouter, Routes and Route** ([React Basis Tutorials, BrowserRouter, Switch and Routes](https://www.reactjstutorials.com/react-basics/22/browserrouter-switch-and-routes)). In your code **BrowserRouter** is missing:

```
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import NavBar from "./components/navbar";
import Products from "./components/products";
import Posts from "./components/posts";
import Home from "./components/home";
import Dashboard from "./components/admin/dashboard";
import ProductDetails from "./components/productDetails";
import NotFound from "./components/notFound";
// Here import BrowserRouter
import {BrowserRouter as Router,Routes, Route} from 'react-router-dom'
import "./App.css";

class App extends Component {

  
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <NavBar />
        <div className="content">
        //Wrap Routes inside BrowserRouter (imported as Router)
         <Router>
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/products" element={< Products sortBy={'newest'} />} />
            <Route path="/posts/2018/06" element={<Posts/>} />
            <Route path="/admin" element={<Dashboard/>} />
            <Route path="/" element={<Home/>} />
          </Routes>
         <Router>
        </div>
      


      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: good observation

Comment: Hello, browser router is in the Index.js code. I have attached it to the original post above. Thank you!

Answer (score -3):

```html
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';
import {BrowserRouter} from 'react-router-dom'

ReactDOM.render(
<BrowserRouter>
       <App/>
</BrowserRouter>, document.getElementById('root'));
registerServiceWorker();
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).